# Edit part of an object in a BehaviorSubject in Angular service

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, observable, behaviorsubject

I've got an app that downloads files. What I want is a separate screen which shows download progress of each file.

This is the function I have that downloads the drawing file (this is using the Cordova FileTransferObject class):

```
    getDownloadDrawingObservable(drawing) {
    let tempFTO = this.fileTransfer.create();

    tempFTO.onProgress((progressEvent) => {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                // loading.setContent('Downloading drawing ' + progress + '%')
                let progress = Math.round(progressEvent.lengthComputable ? progressEvent.loaded * 100 / progressEvent.total : 0);
                drawing["Progress"] = progress + "%";
                console.log(progress + "%")


            })
        } else {
        }
    })

    return Observable.fromPromise(tempFTO.download(drawing["URL"], this.file.dataDirectory + drawing["DrawingNo"] + ".pdf", true, this.getDrawingRequestHeaders))
    // return tempFTO.download(URL, this.file.dataDirectory + drawingNo + ".pdf", true, this.getDrawingRequestHeaders)

}
```

What I'm thinking is creating a separate screen which shows which files are currently downloading and what their progress is.

I'm thinking of using a Behavior Subject to do this. The idea being that I'll subscribe to the Behavior Subject on the 'My Downloads' screen, and that the contents of the Subject will be kept up to date in the download and progress logic.

But in working this through, I've realised that to do this you would have to create an Object, something like this (drawingname, progress downloaded):

```
{drawing1: 55, drawing2: 30}
```

And constantly update the specific part of the object within the BehaviorSubject.

My question(s) are; is this right? Is this the best way to do this? Can you even just update a portion of the BehaviorSubject object and *next()* it to update the value on screen?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: BehaviorSubject holds the last value that you emitted... You have to emit with new value that will overwrite the last value, you can't just edit part of the BS value.

Comment: So it would be a case of using something like `getValue()`, find that part of the object I want to update, and emit again?

Comment: You have your last value when you subscribe to the BehaviorSubject and than in your case, lets say that you wanna change drawing1 to 75 to you simply need to <Your BehaviorSubject>.next({drawing1: 75, drawing2: 30}) and every subscription that subscribed to that BS would get the new status

Comment: BTW, its better to use one value for each download and not hold 1 that project the whole downloads, so you would have like array of subscriptions to each download.

Comment: OK, so on the *My Downloads* page, I'll be subscribing to the BehaviorSubject to get it's contents and displaying that information onscreen.

Then in the Service, that's where I'm going to be calling `next()` to update the progress of the download.

I'm not going to be subscribing to the BehaviorSubject inside the Service, that's why I'm my question is really just about updating.

@dAxx_ I'm thinking of doing is calling behaviourSubject.getValue() to the latest value, then in the `onProgress` function, update the specific part of the object with the latest progress and then emit that

Comment: @dAxx_ By *use one value for each download and not hold 1 that project the whole downloads* do you mean putting an array of object into the BehaviorSubject rather than a single object?

The reason I didn't want to do that is because I'll then have to add array filtering into the logic and it's getting complicated already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174434/discussion-between-bengrah-and-daxx).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer but you gave me an idea, which I hope works for you:

```
  editDisplayName(displayName: string) {
    this.current$.next({...this.current$.getValue(), displayName})
  }
```